# The Junit test fails in Netbeans 11.3 IDE "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, junit

I just installed Netbeans 11.3, on windows 10 running JDK 14. I tried to follow the simple 10 minutes learning tutorial provided at https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/javase-intro.html just to get my feet wet. Everything worked fine until I reached the section under "Creating JUnits Tests". The IDE does a good job in generating the code for the JUnit test class, however, the test fails with `Could not find or load main class` error. Here is the stack trace from the output window:

```
compile-test:
Created dir: C:\Users\....\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyLib\build\test\results
Testsuite: org.me.mylib.LibClassTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.152 sec

Testcase: initializationError(org.me.mylib.LibClassTest):   Caused an ERROR
No runnable methods
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)


Test org.me.mylib.LibClassTest FAILED

The exception seems to take place during the test initialization, internal to the JUnit framework.
```

Here is the code for the test class (LibClassTest from the file LibClassTest.java) generated by the IDE per tutorial example:

```
package org.me.mylib;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
 /**
 * @author hrh74
 */
public class LibClassTest {

    public LibClassTest() {
        System.out.println("Creating LibClassTest");
    }

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of acrostic method, of class LibClass.
     */
    @Test
    public void testAcrostic() {
        System.err.println("Running testAcrostic...");
        String result = LibClass.acrostic(new String[]{"fnord", "polly", "tropism"});
        assertEquals("Correct value", "foo", result);
    }

}
```

---

Here is the code for the class to be tested by the JUnit per the tutorial example:

```
package org.me.mylib;

/**
 *
 * @author hrh74
 */
public class LibClass {

    public static String acrostic(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i].length() > i) {
                b.append(args[i].charAt(i));
            } else {
                b.append('?');
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The content of the buffer " + b);
        return b.toString();
    }

}
```

Any insights would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks again. Please remove the comments. I am about to update my question with new findings. I took your suggestion and tried to make the Junit work first and it failed.

Comment: I would not try to test a class at this point. I'd probably go with just `assertTrue(4 > 1,"4 > 1");` just to isolate if it's the test that doesn't work. I can see from your code that this is JUnit5. I don't think it will work if you selected JUnit4 as described in the mentioned document.

Comment: It could be a missing library. The JUnit5 was split into several. I don't think it's an issue with NetBeans. I'd expect to get results from that in an internet search. I think it may also be caused if you have another class with the name containing the word Test with no @Test in it, but this is just a wild guess.

Comment: @rainer Since you approved this edit: Would you mind removing the normal text from the code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that the putative "JUnit 5" feature in Netbeans 11.3 is not working. The support from the Netbeans mailing list was able to reproduce the bug. The solution is to change the test class. The import statements having org.junit.jupiter should be supplanted by their corresponding org.junit statements. In addition, the JUnit 5 annotations need to change to their corresponding older version. Here is a working example:

```
package org.me.mylib;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LibClassTest {

    public LibClassTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAcrostic() {
        System.err.println("Running testAcrostic...");
        String result = LibClass.acrostic(new String[]{"fnord", "polly", "tropism"});
        assertEquals("Correct value", "foo", result);
    }

}
```